# Timetable implementation in Java?

Tags: java

I need a `Timetable` class that would work like (a rough example to explain the idea):

```
Timetable timetable = new Timetable("Mon-Fri 8:00-17:00");
Date eta = timetable.increment(new Date(), 3, Calendar.HOURS);
```

`eta` should be the point in time, which is exactly 3 hours ahead of current time, but only the time between 8:00 and 17:00 is taken into account. This may sound like an interview question, but I need such a class for a business purpose and I suspect that some open source implementation exists already.

Comment: Can't really understand what is the purpose, but it seems like an ideal recipe for [joda-time.sf.net](http://joda-time.sf.net) in action.

Comment: Did you check [this](http://code.google.com/p/unimaner/)? Surely some useful classes there.

Comment: To be sure I understood your need, I guess that if "new Date()" returned "friday 16:00", eta would be set to "monday, 10:00" ??

Comment: @zim2001 you got it absolutely right

Answer (score -1):

I think this is very close to parse the string into a date then use **java.util.Calendar** to either add or subtract the date.

check this
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#add(int, int)

```
      // create a calendar
      Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance()

      // print current date
      System.out.println("The current date is : " + cal.getTime());

      // add 20 days to the calendar
      cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 20);
      System.out.println("20 days later: " + cal.getTime());

      // subtract 2 months from the calendar
      cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, -2);
      System.out.println("2 months ago: " + cal.getTime());

      // subtract 5 year from the calendar
      cal.add(Calendar.YEAR, -5);
      System.out.println("5 years ago: " + cal.getTime());
```

Comment: How this explanation of a basic functionality of `Calendar` class is related to the question asked? I need a timetable mechanism.